# MATLAB fminsearch over a sphere

Tags: matlab, optimization

I have a function defined on the surface of a sphere, `f(theta,phi)`, that I want to minimise in MATLAB. As far as I see, using `fminsearch(@(x) f(x), [theta,phi])` has the issue being unbounded, which I guess reduces optimality. Any suggestion?

Comment: If you have the optimization toolbox you can probably use `fmincon`. Not sure how much the nonlinearity of polar-to-Cartesian affects accuracy.

Comment: Why should an unbounded optimization reduce optimality? Usually, it is the other way around

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking to do is optimize over a manifold which is not trivial and I don't know if you can rope `fminsearch` into doing it nicely. The `manopt` library (www.manopt.org) is a Matlab library that does exactly this, though. In fact the very first example in the tutorial section is an optimization on a sphere.

Answer (score 0):

A bounded search is actually bad when working on a sphere. Imagine if your function is simply the distance to Tokio, a perfect smooth function any numeric search should solve. If you where using a bounded search and your starting point is somewhere in the US, then fminsearch would follow the gradient until it hits the anti meridian. No way to continue because the boundary is hit. Similar problems can occur at the pole.

You could redefine your problem to be in infinite space. Whenever your longitude exceeds the [-180,180] you just go another round, normalizing it to this range. A little more tricky is the latitude. Imagine you are at 10°E and walk to the north pole, your latitude increases until it reaches 90°N. When you further continue you are suddenly at 170°W and your latitude decreases.

If you manage this transformation and let fminsearch search in infinite space, the advantage is that neither the poles nor anti meridian will stop your search.